# How to change order of characters in a string? Python

Tags: python, string, reverse

I have a string `"ATCGATCG"` and I want it to be reversed so its `"GCTAGTCA"`. I thought about using:

```
data_r2[total:]+s[0]
```

Where total is the result from a counting script I have which will count the number of characters in the string. I realise that this will rotate the string and just end up with the same order if totally rotated which isn't what I want at all.

Does anyone know how to do this so it is the input string reversed so the right most character is now the left most character etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
"ATCGATCG"[::-1] == "GCTAGCTA"
```

This uses slice notation, from the start to the end stepping by negative one.

Comment: It's also probably a million different duplicates on SO :)

Comment: This doesn't produce the OP's desired output.  He could have made a typo though...

Comment: @iCodez ha I didn't actually read the desired output! I'm assuming that MUST be a typo. If not, please let me know OP and further clarify your question

Comment: Yeah it was a typo, as I said I wanted to reverse the string which this does so thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative but slower way.

```
In [2]: s="ATCGATCG"

In [3]: ''.join(reversed(s))
Out[3]: 'GCTAGCTA'
```